# Remove surplus vertical space in tabular

Tags: tables, fontsize

I noticed that the tabular environment produces surplus vertical space on top of `\baselineskip` (as does LaTeX by default but that part can be avoided by using `\offinterlineskip`):

\documentclass{article}

```
\begin{document}
    \offinterlineskip
    \fontsize{40pt}{40pt}\selectfont

    No vertical spacing (bars touch):\\\textbar\\\textbar

    \begin{tabular}{l}
        Tabular produces vertical space:\\\textbar\\\textbar
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make `tabular` omit that vertical space? Seems I have not found the proper length to set yet...

---

## To add to the accepted answer:

Turns out most of the confusion was due to the issue described in a follow-up question, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410251/152311

The font size of 40 pt I used in the example to highlight the issue unfortunately shows the problem of not fully scalable fonts at its worst and introduces a large vertical spacing even for normal text which I tried to suppress with `\offinterlineskip` subsequently. This command does not affect the `tabular` environment in the same way, though.

It turns out the "fix" is as simple as adding the `fix-cm` package or using a scalable font like lmodern:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
%   \offinterlineskip
\fontsize{40pt}{40pt}\selectfont

No vertical spacing (bars touch):\\\textbar\\\textbar

\begin{tabular}{l}
    Tabular produces vertical space:\\\textbar\\\textbar
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the sudden increase in font size (not properly visible in the screenshots due to different scaling unfortunately).

The bars are almost touching also in the `tabular` example now (**help on how to remove the remaining difference would be appreciated but is mostly academic now**).

Using `\fontsize{40pt}{80pt}\selectfont` causes the behavior I desired initially (e.g. a proper double line spacing in the text and the `tabular`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables follow different rules. A strut is added at each line (`.7\baselineskip` above the base line and `.3\baselineskip` below). This is modified by a factor `\arraystretch`. It can be redefined to zero:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        Tabular without vertical space:\\\textbar\\\textbar
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question but the long-term goal is to be able to set what CSS calls the `line-height` property on the tabular - redefining `\arraystretch` to zero prevents this (it will always be zero).

Comment: @EduardBraun The default value of `\arraystretch` is `1`. It can be redefined to other values. But keep in mind, LaTeX tables work differently from CSS.

Comment: Yeah, I'm struggling with this a bit right now... I had assumed `\fontsize{40pt}{40pt}` in the example above would put my lines directly next to each other and `fontsize{40pt}{60pt}` would be like setting `line-height:1.5;` in CSS - apparently it is not. I'll have to read up on that a bit before maybe asking a more targeted question.

Comment: This leaves the cell contents too close together. Isn't there a way to extend the length of the lines?