# Understanding line height / line spacing / baselineskip in LaTeX

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

I tried for a while now to figure out how LaTeX is determining the spacing between two lines but instead of getting clearer I'm more and more confused (and it seems the Internet is mostly confused, too), so let's see if turning it into a question can clarify it!

## The naive assumption

First of all my naive understanding of "line height" or what I assumed was the value stored in `\baselineskip` was the following
[image]

Consequently I assumed setting `\baselineskip` equal to font size should result in lines "touching" each other - no actual empty space between lines (including full ascenders and descenders of the font).

## Reality seems to differ

However it became clear to me, that this can't be true. Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% font size = \baselineskip - should result in lines "touching", shouldn't it?
\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\textbar The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\\
\textbar The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}\selectfont
\textbar The quick brown fox...\\
\textbar The quick brown fox...

\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont
\textbar The quick brown fox...\\
\textbar The quick brown fox...

\end{document}
```

[image]

While my assumption seems to hold for smaller font sizes, the larger the font size the more obvious it becomes this can't be the whole truth!

## Set line height in multiples of font size?

Similar confusion [is also apparent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65849/confusion-onehalfspacing-vs-spacing-vs-word-vs-the-world) for people trying to set the line spacing to a specific multiple of the font size.

Using `\renewcommand*\baselinestretch{1.5}\selectfont` or similar does many things - but not result in what one expects to be a one-and-a-half line spacing!

This even resulted in the creation of the [setspace](https://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package, which is often recommended to achieve the desired result. Looking at the source reveals however, that the authors were not fully able to understand what LaTeX was doing either:

```
% GT:  Sat 28 Sep 1996:  No, I don't know understand the line spacing
% algorithms!  If someone (LaTeX team) can enlighten me as to the
% general rule, please do!  It would be very pleasant if setspace.sty
% were suited for document font sizes other than 10, 11 and 12 pt.
```

And in fact the package specifies some hardcoded values for the three font sizes mentioned to achieve consistent line spacing at least for the most commonly used font sizes.

## Why care?

Obvious question: Why care so much if whatever TeX does seems to "look good" at least.

In my specific case I want to implement something in TeX that works like the `line-height` property in CSS/SVG, so I can set the line spacing precisely in multiples of the font size.
So far a solution is elusive to me which kind off bugs me because I always thought this was the stuff TeX was supposed to be superior in, but it turns out in this particular case it's reluctant to comply.

Therfore I hope you can give me the clarity I need to implement what I want and explain what spacings control the actual distance of two font baselines in LaTeX and how `\baselineskip` plays into this.

Comment: It seems that you need `\offinterlineskip` — but, curiously, not if you compile with luatex rather than pdftex.

Comment: Might make a difference if you are using fully scalable fonts, versus fonts that come in quantized font sizes.

Comment: @RobtAll almost all fonts available in TeXLive are scalable format these days

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your first assumption and picture of `\baselineskip` were correct, but

> Consequently I assumed setting `\baselineskip` equal to font size should result in lines "touching" each other

Is wrong for two separate reasons.

Firstly the "font size" is an essentially arbitrary number assigned by the font designer `\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont` selects a font with nominal size 10pt and `\baselineskip` equal to 10pt but the actual height of the letters (especially parentheses and accented captitals, or even unaccented capitals) may be more than 10pt. So this may or may not result in `\baselineskip` glue being added depending if the height of the letters actually used on the line is more or less than 10pt.

Secondly teX does not force the baselineskip by using no space (or negative space) two over-height lines do not over-print, being set to a forced `\baselineskip` spacing. If the space to be added would be less than the parameter `\lineskiplimit` then a length `\lineskip` is used instead.

By default in the standard classes `\lineskip` is 1pt so you will see a minimum 1pt separation if the baselines would touch but (slightly strangely) `\lineskiplimit` is 0pt so the distance can approach zero without `\lineskip` being used, which will cause a "jump" in interline space if the height of the content is gradually increased.

If you add

```
\showoutput
\showboxdepth=3
```

to your test file, note first that it says

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 5.12pt have occurred.
```

So the fonts used were not always the size requested (but `\baselineskip` was always exactly as requested) this explains why the effects are more apparent at some sizes. The log will show

```
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 426.9944fil
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 2.5
...\hbox(7.5+2.5)x345.0, glue set 143.77742fil []
...\penalty 300
...\glue(\baselineskip) 0.0
...\hbox(7.5+2.5)x345.0, glue set 143.77742fil []
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 1.945
...\hbox(15.555+5.185)x345.0, glue set 152.1931fil []
...\penalty 300


...\glue(\lineskip) 1.0


...\hbox(15.555+5.185)x345.0, glue set 152.1931fil []
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 6.155
...\hbox(18.66+6.22)x345.0, glue set 113.70607fil []
...\penalty 300
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.12
...\hbox(18.66+6.22)x345.0, glue set 113.70607fil []
...\glue -5.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.55556
..\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 170.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

If you allow the fonts at any size by adding `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` as the first line you get no font size warning

[image]

and a log of

```
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 427.45435fil
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 2.5
...\hbox(7.5+2.5)x345.0, glue set 143.77742fil []
...\penalty 300
...\glue(\baselineskip) 0.0
...\hbox(7.5+2.5)x345.0, glue set 143.77742fil []
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 2.5
...\hbox(15.0+5.0)x345.0, glue set 159.07242fil []
...\penalty 300
...\glue(\baselineskip) 0.0
...\hbox(15.0+5.0)x345.0, glue set 159.07242fil []
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 2.5
...\hbox(22.5+7.5)x345.0, glue set 66.10855fil []
...\penalty 300
...\glue(\baselineskip) 0.0
...\hbox(22.5+7.5)x345.0, glue set 66.10855fil []
...\glue -5.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.55556
..\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 170.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

Comment: Thanks, I never thought to blame the font! Using `\usepackage{lmodern}` fixes the unexpected spaces just as well (I was using it at one point but removed it for this minimum example which only added to the overall confusion)

Comment: @EduardBraun note it's not the font so much as latex's declaration of it. The computer modern fonts for compatibility reasons by default are only loaded at the sizes available as bitmaps in 1985, even though scalable type1 versions have been freely available for 20 years or so. It's really hard to change that default, but the `fix-cm` package just loads cm the way most other fonts are loaded, and allows arbitrary size, so yes using lmodern or more or less any other font package has a similar effect here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is indeed slightly strange that the value of`\lineskiplimit` is 0pt while that of `\lineskip` is 1pt (without stretch). Wouldn't setting `\lineskiplimit` to 1pt be more consistent? (Another vertical spacing problem I have never understood is why the value of `\belowdisplayskip` is different from that of `\belowdisplayshortskip`, but this probably means I am a typographic heretic...)

Comment: @MichelFioc D Knuth set it that way in plain and L Lamport followed suit in latex 2.x and  we didn't change it in latex2e, but I don't think it can be justified for reasons other than compatibility

Comment: Is there a native command that holds the height of a single line? Or does that quantity depend on the font size? Thanks!

Comment: @zyy not sure i understand that comment but `\baselineskip` is the target height and is used unless the content is too big to fit, as described in this answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, so you mean that the `\baselineskip` is essentially the line height plus empty space between two lines, is that right?

Comment: @zyy the site doesn't really support asking comments on old questions, by default tex lays down lines of text so their baselines are `\baselineskip` apart. There is no separate "line height" measure.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, that make sense.

Answer (score 12):

The second test includes 1 pt `\lineskip` between lines and the third test has the lines not exactly 30 pt height because `\usepackage{fix-cm}` was not used.

Comment: +1 a lot more succinct than my answer but same information:-)